# How to get the date/time at which an image was taken  using CCR EXIF?

Tags: delphi, exif

using CCR EXIF  http://delphihaven.wordpress.com/ccr-exif/  how can I get the time at which an image was taken?

(I am open to using something else, so long as I can use Delphi, but everyone says that CCR EXIF is best; I just can't find this in the sparse docs)

Comment: You could have at least looked at the fields in TExifData yourself, right?  This seems a silly question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to use this (please note I haven't tested this, just verified the [`DateTimeOriginal`](http://www.awaresystems.be/imaging/tiff/tifftags/privateifd/exif/datetimeoriginal.html) tag against what returns the `DateTimeOriginal` property and they match).

```
uses
  CCR.Exif;

procedure ShowDateTimeOriginal(const FileName: string);
var
  ExifData: TExifData;
begin
  ExifData := TExifData.Create;
  try
    ExifData.LoadFromGraphic(FileName);
    ShowMessage(DateTimeToStr(ExifData.DateTimeOriginal));
  finally
    ExifData.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Yup, that did it. Thanks!  Btw, do you know of any good URLs for CCR EXIF? As I said, the docs seem sparse

Comment: You're welcome. About the links to some resources for CCR EXIF, just those you can Google, maybe this [`documentation`](http://ccr-exif.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/Documentation.pdf) might be useful.

Comment: I already googled & didn't find much help (and the doc is included in the distro), which is why I asked here . Thanks again for the answer.